# Hotmail not accepting my emails from my email server. [dyn dns]

Tags: email-server, gmail, dyndns, email

I am using DynDNS to do name resolution and would like to send emails to Hotmail and Gmail.

Gmail marks them as spam, while Hotmail just blocks everything.

How do I make Gmail and Hotmail know that my mail server is legit?

My DNS is as follows:

```
A companyName.com x.x.x.x

MX 10 companyName.com.
```

This is OK, right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are likely using a dynamic 'consumer' IP from your ISP.  Most of these are blacklisted on Barracuda and similar RBL's due to various malware and spam sent over them without most users knowing (which is one of the many reasons you should use a static IP for any business needs.)  You can try and get the IP removed but it will be wasted effort as the next one you pickup will have the same issues.  Also I'm going to assume since you are not using a static IP that you are not using a business account with your ISP.  Many server roles are against the ToS for many ISPs (mail, web, terminal servers, etc...) at least in the US.